# Keyboard and mouse only work on 1st, 3rd, 5th etc startup. Most bizzare situation I've ever seen

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop

On a brand new installation of win 7 x64, the system fails to recognize mouse and keyboard after every second boot up.

This is very odd. I am thinking that something has to do with bios or something. 
The laptop is a `Toshiba Satellite A300 17s`. Even with the latest drivers and everything.

The really strange fact is that there can't be a memory issue, nor a disk issue. This happens even after a complete shutdown with the battery removed.

Another fact is that the other buttons (volume, etc) above the keyboard still work, also the wifi switch works (I can see the device go off). The system seems to be up and running. Everything works fine except I cannot interact with the system.

Also, this is the reason I formatted it. This was also happening before the format.

Comment: your computer is prejudiced against nonprime/even numbers.

Comment: Does the keyboard work in the BIOS on both Odd and Even boots?  How does it behave if you try booting to Safe Mode for a few (re)boots?

Comment: Did you ever have another version of the OS installed on it, that did not have that problem?

Comment: I had Win 7 Home x86. Same issue with all updates installed..

Comment: http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/ToshibaM45/Satellite_M45_disassembly_1.htm  the only logical sounding thing from the web was a bad capacitor. But that doesnt explain both items going.  lots of people out there with toshibakeys. Other laptops they said if you get it working reinstall drivers.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check into a BIOS update. Also, when you remove the battery and power cord, press and hold the power button for a few seconds. Your laptop's capacitors can still have a charge with all power sources removed. by pressing the power button with cord and battery out, it will discharge the capacitors and allow a fresh cold boot.

Comment: I have done the power button thing because I was curious on when this thing happens. Didn't help